# Android: Intent Filter pathpattern and host

Tags: android, intentfilter

In my application, I want to handle links that use the following pattern:

```
https://abc.abconline.com/plugin/callback/?code=hgdfre_55cjgdfhaskzkjcedcgdffcdk&scope=orders&state=unjcjksansygdsfvcvc
```

I tried with a different pattern nothing worked

```
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="abc.abconline.com"
                android:scheme="https"
                android:pathPattern="/plugin/callback/..*" />
        </intent-filter>
```

and

```
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="abc.abconline.com"
                android:scheme="https"
                android:pathPattern="/plugin/callback/..*/" />
        </intent-filter>
```

I've been reading the docs and questions on how to use android:pathPattern but I really don't understand what I'm supposed to type in.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the / after each paths...

Try this one...

```
<intent-filter>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

    <data
        android:host="abc.abconline.com"
        android:scheme="https"
        android:pathPattern="/plugin\\/callback\\/.*" />
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in the answer by @PraveenSP you need to escape certain characters in your path patterns. Citing from the official documentation on the [`<data>`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element) element:

> Because '`\`' is used as an escape character when the string is read from XML (before it is parsed as a pattern), you will need to double-escape: For example, a literal '`*`' would be written as "`\\*`" and a literal '`\`' would be written as "`\\\\`". This is basically the same as what you would need to write if constructing the string in Java code.

However, in your case the most likely culprit is the `..*/` at the end of your path pattern `/plugin/callback/..*/`. This matches a literal `.`, then an arbitrary amount of characters via `.*` and then finally a literal `/`. However, your example URI doesn't conform to this pattern. What you most likely meant to write is `/plugin/callback/.*`.